# ListView with a single expanded tile at a time

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-listview

I am trying to create a `ListView` widget that contains `ExpansionTiles` and I want to have only a single tile expanded at a time. I am using quite a bit of data, so I am using `ListView.builder` I am getting an error:

```
Error: Assertion failed:
_state != null
```

Documentation also specifies that you cannot call controller methods inside a build method.

My code looks like this:

```
return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: data.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ExpansionTile(
              controller: expansionControllers[index],
              leading: Text(data[index].code),
              title: Text(data[index].name),
              onExpansionChanged: (value) async {
                if (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    prevIndexExpanded = index;
                  });

                  //Do stuff
                }
              },
              children: [...]
            );
          },
        );
```

where I have a `prevIndexExpanded` which tracks the currently expanded tile and I have generated a list of `ExpansionTileController()` for each tile.

```
final expansionControllers = List.generate(
          data.length,
          (index) => ExpansionTileController(),
        );
```

So to be clear: when selecting a tile it should expand and if there is another already expanded tile, it should collapse, so there is only one expanded at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I was making the mistake of generating the list inside of the `build` method of the Widget, therefore it was generating a new list on every rebuild and the controllers wouldn't match. After taking it outside, everything is working as expected.

**Quick note:** If you are using a `ListView.builder` with a lot of `ExpansionTiles`, you should specify the `initiallyExpanded` property, since while scrolling, the ListView rebuilds and it will collapse expanded tiles otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want a ListView but instead, I think you might want to use a Silver List 
[SliverList & SliverGrid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORiTTaVY6mM)

If you still want to follow the ListView approach, you can look up this link on how to [Create lists with different types of items](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/mixed-list)

You must define your own build method, in order to define the structure of your items.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! In my case, it turned out that I was generating the controllers list inside the build method of the widget, so the controllers in the ExpansionTile and the list wouldn't match. After taking the list generation outside, everything is working as expected. 

I don't think SliverList makes much particular sense in my case, since I want to just show data without much fanciness, but I will look into it, maybe I missed something.